# return named function in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following javascript:

```
Function.prototype.debounce = function (threshold, execAsap) {

    var func = this, timeout;

    return function debounced () {
       //body
    }
};
```

How can I return a named function like this in coffeescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can't name functions in Coffeescript. The reason is given in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ) -- grep for "Is there any way to name functions, for reflection and recursion?" If you really need to embed a name, you could use backticks to embed raw Javascript.