# CoffeeScript naming lambdas

Tags: javascript, lambda, coffeescript

In JavaScript, you can name lambda functions

```js
(function() {
    ...
}).call()

doSomething(param1, param2, function() {
    ...
});
```

like

```js
(function main() {
    ...
}).call()

doSomething(param1, param2, function callback() {
    ...
});
```

So they are not anonymous and error tracing becomes clearer to the programmer -- especially useful with Node.js to avoid (or at least understand) callback hells.

I am currently getting into CoffeeScript to try and see if it makes my coding clearer/faster, but can't get around to naming throw-away functions like these ones.

```coffee
(->
    ...
).call()

doSomething param1, param2, ->
    ...
```

Is there a way to name these functions in CoffeeScript? Although not critical, I would see that as a big fault in CS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return named function in coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462589/return-named-function-in-coffeescript) and lots of others that can be found by searching for ["coffeescript function name"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoffeescript%5D+function+name)

Comment: If that other question's answer is the only one, that's a big flaw.

Comment: It's actually more accurately a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029514/immediately-invoked-named-functions

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029514/immediately-invoked-named-functions).

Basically, you can't do that -- CoffeeScript does not allow the naming of functions. They say it's because of IE9 compatibility, but what if you don't really care about that? (Come on, even low information users nowadays know IE8 and lower aren't meant for use, and in my personal opinion those browsers died together with Win XP.)

Back to the answer, CoffeeScript only accepts function expressions, as opposed to declarations -- meaning I can't name a lambda function unless I assign it to a var and pass it as a parameter later.

Answer (score 0):

Also discussed in the FAQ: `Q: Is there any way to name functions, for reflection and recursion?`
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ

It lists a number of related repository issues, including:
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/366